# Как сделать динамическое меню в Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, ui-bootstrap

Как сделать динамическое меню в Bootstrap, как показано на картинке?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

> Navbars are responsive meta components that serve as navigation headers for your application or site. They begin collapsed (and are toggleable) in mobile views and become horizontal as the available viewport width increases.

Comment: Почему не на русском ответ? При таких ответах хешкод и нафиг ненужен.

Comment: @shatal потому что это прямая цитата, очевидно

Answer (score 0):

Одним navbar здесь не обойтись.
Кнопка справа вверху на 2-ом скрине при таком раскладе не нужна, т.к. в неё, согласно этому ТЗ ничего не прячется (если всё-таки нужно – см. сниппет http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-lateral-slide-menu).

В данном случае, если интересует IE9+:

```
@media (max-width: 768) { // меньше 768
  .content-menu > ul > li{ 
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }  
}
```